# How to add *junit* to *spec.libraries* in generated podspec?

Tags: j2objc-gradle

I am using the Gradle J2ObjC plugin to translate Java code in the pure-Java modules of my project to Objective-C. I have a need for the generated `podspec` file in the `build/j2objcOutputs` folder of one of my Java modules to contain a `junit` entry in the `spec.libraries` list. Currently it is defined as follows:

```
spec.libraries = 'ObjC', 'guava', 'javax_inject', 'jre_emul', 'jsr305', 'z', 'icucore'
```

Is there something that I can add to the `build.gradle` file of my Java module to make this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been unable to figure out how to do this with the J2Objc Gradle plugin and have had to resort to putting the following in the "Other linker flags" in Xcode for my tests target:

```
$(inherited)
-l"junit"
```

I'm marking this as the solution until someone can suggest otherwise.